# How to avoid attribute-operation-attribute-exists when calling writer.setAttribute() in CKEditor5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am developing a simple CKEditor5 plug-in.  Part of the plug-in is a "Command" that executes like this:

```
execute(options) {
    const contentItemUtils = this.editor.plugins.get('ContentItemUtils');
    const contentItemElement = contentItemUtils.getClosestSelectedContentItemElement(this.editor.model.document.selection);

    this.editor.model.change(writer => {
        writer.setAttribute('width', options.width, contentItemElement);
    });
}
```

The problem happens when I call `writer.setAttribute`.  I always get an error like this:

> CKEditorError: **attribute-operation-attribute-exists** {"node":{"attributes":{"contentId":"CORE08954D2EBB7042799E0A059DC90703DD","contentName":"Paris","contentType":"Destination","contentTypeDisplay":"Destination","contentViewing":"draft","categoryLayout":"overview","detailPageId":"","alignment":""},"name":"contentItem"},"key":"width"}
>
> Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-attribute-operation-attribute-exists

What I am trying to do -- set a model attribute to a new value -- seems fairly simple.

**Is there a restriction about updating model attributes that already have values?**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up first removing the attribute and then adding it :

```
    editor.model.change( writer => {
        const element = selection.getSelectedElement();
        writer.removeAttribute( 'format', element)

        editor.model.change( writer => {
            writer.setAttribute( 'format', 'date', element)
        });
    } );
```